# how to reset record number when equal 1000 in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a requirement to reset record number when it is 1000 and start again from 1.

I am using the below code.

```
global numbervar LastRecordCount;
global numbervar PageRecordCount;

if recordnumber>=1000 then 
(
PageRecordCount:=RecordNumber;
LastRecordCount:=PagerecordCount;
)
else
(
PageRecordCount:=RecordNumber-LastRecordCount;
//LastRecordCount:=recordnumber;

);

PageRecordCount;
```

it works correctly in the first execution.

now my real record number = 3233

and it show me = 2233

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the Remainder() function, but the description of the situation is not very clear.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: It's equivalent to the Modulus (x Mod y) function. Crystal Reports has very good online help for any of their functions.

Comment: Remainder(3233, 1000) returns 233.  Is that what you are trying to achieve?